# Value Change Event and Click Event

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF page with value change listeners on input field, and a button to save the changes. When I change a value on them and tab out of the field, the validation fires and everything works fine. But when I change a value and, without tabbing out, click on the Save button, the value change event fires, but its Button's click action is not fired. How to get around this so that I can have both events firing sequentially?

Comment: can you provide your program code in here..it will helpful to give better solution.

Answer (score 0):

With "p:clientValidator" in the fields you want to validate and the property  validateClient="true" in your p:comandButton primefaces does the work for you.

Take a look at this example:
[validate client](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/event.xhtml)

Comment: Thank you Julio. I need to call server side validation so client validation would not be sufficient in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that its beacause of multiple ajax requests...

What happens is when you clicking on your submit button your input filed is getting blurred and thus triggering its chnage event which in turn sends an ajax to your server which in turn making your submit button ajax request to get lost (you can't send two ajax at once/one click)

I suggest you to replace your input *change* event into *keyup* event to prevent your double ajax sending scneario

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion will solve the problem but triggering the validation on keyup would mean we have no way of detecting weather user has finished editing a field.

Comment: You can move the validation to the submit button, just write a custom validator that will check those input on submit